# Delphi 2009 - Get file's Owner name

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-2009

How do I get the owner of a file in Delphi 2009?

[image: properties]

I got a function which get files attributes like this:

```
type
  TCustomFileInfo= record
    CompanyName,
    Owner,
    SpecialBuild: string;
    procedure Clear;
  end;

function GetFileInfo(const FileName: string): TCustomFileInfo;
type
  PLandCodepage = ^TLandCodepage;
  TLandCodepage = record
    wLanguage,
    wCodePage: word;
  end;
var
  dummy,
  len: cardinal;
  buf, pntr: pointer;
  lang: string;
begin
  len := GetFileVersionInfoSize(PChar(FileName), dummy);
  if len = 0 then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  GetMem(buf, len);
  try
    if not GetFileVersionInfo(PChar(FileName), 0, len, buf) then
      RaiseLastOSError;

    if not VerQueryValue(buf, '\VarFileInfo\Translation\', pntr, len) then
      RaiseLastOSError;

    lang := Format('%.4x%.4x', [PLandCodepage(pntr)^.wLanguage, PLandCodepage(pntr)^.wCodePage]);

    // Get Company's name, if available...
    if VerQueryValue(buf, PChar('\StringFileInfo\' + lang + '\CompanyName'), pntr, len){ and (@len <> nil)} then
      result.CompanyName := PChar(pntr);
  finally
    FreeMem(buf);
  end;
end;
```

...which works fine for this **CompanyName** attribute, but I don't how to get the owner.

Moreover, when I try to use this same method for a file that **doesn't have a file version number**, `GetFileVersionInfoSize` doesn't work, which makes sense, since the file doesn't have a version number at all.

Is there an alternative method for `GetFileVersionInfoSize`, or another way to get the file's owner? I'm not very used to windows apis, so I really don't know if this is the right way of achieving what I want (getting owner's name).

Comment: This is the file system property you want?

Comment: `GetFileVersionInfoSize()` returning 0 is not an error unless `GetLastError()` says an error actually occured. `RaiseLastOSError()` will always raise an `EOSError` exception even if `GetLastError()` returns 0.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I took a picture, unfortunately is in portuguese, but I think you can understand: [picture](https://puu.sh/uywsh/5f59bf2dc9.png)

Comment: @RemyLebeau that's a good point. What I meant with *doesn't work* is it returns zero like you said, I think this is the expected behavior for files without a version number. I wanted to get the owner of some XML files...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Information about a file's ownership is not stored in the version resource, so you can't use `VerQueryValue()` to access it.

Ownership is related to a file's security, so you need to use [`GetFileSecurity()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446639.aspx) or [`GetNamedSecurityInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446645.aspx) instead if you have a filename, or [`GetUserObjectSecurity()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446675.aspx) if you have a open handle to the file.

Either way, you would supply a [`SECURITY_INFORMATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379573.aspx) value as input specifying the type of information you want to retrieve.  In this case, you would use `OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION` to request the SID of the file's owner.  If successful, you can then use [`LookupAccountSid()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379166.aspx) or WMI to get the owner's name.

Comment: After your answer, I searched a usage example for `GetFileSecurity()` and found [this sample](http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?p=194849). I could get user and domain, thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 2):

Just for complement the Remy answer, this a is sample code for getting the file Owner, using the [Win32_LogicalFileOwner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394179(v=vs.85).aspx) and [Win32_LogicalFileSecuritySetting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394180(v=vs.85).aspx)  WMI Classes.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj,
  Variants;


function GetFileOwner(const AFileName : string) : string;
var
  LSWbemLocator, LWMIService, LObjects, LObject : OLEVariant;
  FileName       : string;
  LEnumerator    : IEnumvariant;
  iValue         : LongWord;
begin;
  Result := '';
  LSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  LWMIService   := LSWbemLocator.ConnectServer('localhost', 'root\CIMV2', '', '');

  //Escape the `\` chars in the FileName value because the '\' is a reserved character in WMI.
  FileName        := StringReplace(AFileName, '\', '\\', [rfReplaceAll]);
  LObjects   := LWMIService.ExecQuery(Format('ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_LogicalFileSecuritySetting="%s"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalFileOwner ResultRole = Owner', [FileName]));

  LEnumerator  := IUnknown(LObjects._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  if LEnumerator.Next(1, LObject, iValue) = 0 then
     Result := string(LObject.AccountName);   //
end;

begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
     Writeln(GetFileOwner('C:\Foo.Bar'));
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```